# How to get the output date format as 2016-05-03T01:38:54.003Z in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime

Input time format:

> 2016-05-03 01:38:54

Ouput time format:

> 2016-05-03T01:38:54.003Z

Here what is `.003`, is it millisecond or microsecond?

And in PHP the microsecond format is `'u'`, but when I am trying to use this using the following code snippet, I am getting 6 digits after the decimal point:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");

echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z', strtotime("2016-05-03 01:38:54"));
```

I am getting the output as:

> `2016-05-03T01:38:54.000000Z`

But in this output after the decimal point it is showing 6 digit, which I want to change it to 3 digit. How can I do that?

So how should I get the output format?

Comment: Z is Timezone offset in seconds. The offset for timezones west of UTC is always negative, and for those east of UTC is always positive.

Comment: This link has all you need. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: PHP doesn't use micro-seconds, but if you need go for `microtime`. and this will do: `echo str_replace("+05:30", ".000Z", date('c', strtotime('2016-05-03 01:38:54')));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
    $t = strtotime('2016-05-03 01:38:54');
    $micro = sprintf("%06d",($t - floor($t)) * 1000000);
    $d = new DateTime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$micro, $t) );

    $new= $d->Format("Y-m-d\T H:i:s.u\Z");
    echo substr($new, 0, -4) ."Z";

//output 2016-05-03T 01:38:54.030Z
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class as follows:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = new DateTime('2016-05-03 01:38:54', $tz );
echo substr($date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u'), 0, -3) ."Z";
// 2016-05-03T01:38:54.000Z
```

http://ideone.com/Wrrve9

---

According to `PHP` [date manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

> `u` Microseconds (added in PHP 5.2.2). Note that `date()` will always
>   generate `000000` since it takes an **integer** parameter, whereas
>   DateTime::`format()` does support microseconds if `DateTime` was created
>   with **microseconds**.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$t = microtime(true);
$micro = sprintf("%06d",($t - floor($t)) * 1000000);
$d = new DateTime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$micro, $t) );

print $d->format("Y-m-d\T H:i:s.u\Z"); // note at point on "u"
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution might be a modified version of *adityabhai at gmail dot com*'s comment on http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s' . substr((string)microtime(), 1, 4));
```